# Which is used more often, 日没 and 日落

Tags: mandarin, usage

Both 日没 and 日落 express sunset but which one is often more widely used?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at Google hits, you can see a clear distinction:

**[日落](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=ipB_XP3bAtCFr7wPgY-soAQ&q=%22%E6%97%A5%E8%90%BD%22&btnK=Google%20Search&oq=%22%E6%97%A5%E8%90%BD%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i7i30l2j0j0i7i30l3j0j0i7i30j0.686.1600..2082...0.0..0.483.1550.0j1j4-3......0....1j2..gws-wiz.....0..35i39.4NdZ2zSrzwE)**

> About 42,700,000 results

**[日没](https://www.google.com/search?ei=jJB_XMr5MYeTr7wPvviSyAg&q=%22%E6%97%A5%E6%B2%A1%22&oq=%22%E6%97%A5%E6%B2%A1%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i4i30l10.2842.6368..6448...3.0..0.579.1564.2-4j5-1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0j0i7i4i10i30.Y6Yq10g7bj8)**

> About 13,500,000 results

I've never heard 日没 in real life, you might hear it more in Japanese.

Answer (score 3):

[日没](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%B2%92) is more literary. You are more likely to find it in novel. But not in day to day speech

日落 is more colloquial and common in text

*Japanese also use '日没'  (にちぼつ) for 'sunset'*

Answer (score 1):

In practice, if you say "ri4 mo4", I would think you mean 日末("*the end of the day*"), instead of 日没. 日落 is the common word for sunset. Never seen 日没 before.